# JAX-RS/Jersey path parameter regex for a simple string

Tags: java, regex, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to match strings `v1` and `v2`. For that, I am trying the following regex : `^v(1|2)` (I also tried with `$` which is probably what I need). When I test it in http://www.regextester.com/, it seems to work fine. But when I used it in JAX-RS path expression it doesn't work. The expression I use is below:

`@Path("/blah/{ver:^v(1|2)}/ep")`

Is there anything specific to JAX-RS that I am missing?

Comment: The [JAX-RS specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311) contains template pattern examples which do not use anchors (that is, `^` and `$`), so I'm guessing they should not be used.  Whether they are the cause of your problem, I can't say for sure (and I don't have a server on which I can test it).

Comment: @VGR I just dig through the spec and the URI templates are placed inside a capturing group (3.7.3) so that eliminates anchors

Comment: @Tunaki So it does.  The presence of `^` in the question is probably the reason for the failed match, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempt does not work because of the anchor `^`. Quoting from the [JAX-RS specification, chapter 3.7.3](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-1.1-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/jax_rs-1_1-mrel-spec.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> The function `R(A)` converts a URI path template annotation `A` into a regular expression as follows:
>
> 1. URI encode the template, ignoring URI template variable specifications.
> 2. Escape any regular expression characters in the URI template, again ignoring URI template variable specifications.
> 3. **Replace each URI template variable with a capturing group containing the specified regular expression** or `‘([ˆ/]+?)’` if no regular expression is specified.
> 4. If the resulting string ends with `‘/’` then remove the final character.
> 5. Append `‘(/.*)?’` to the result.

Because each URI templates is placed inside a capturing group, you can't embed anchors in it.

As such, the following will work and will match `v1` or `v2`:

```
@Path("/blah/{ver:v[12]}/ep")
```

Comment: What if you want to use anchors? Is there an alternative?

Comment: @500865 Why would you want to use anchors? I don't see a specific need to match the beginning or end of a String.

Comment: Also, if there is no regex in the template, the variable is replaced by an expression '([^/]+?)' which contains an anchor.

Comment: @500865 No it's inside a group (i.e. `[]`), so it means "not /". It isn't an anchor here (same character but different meaning).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (without anchors):

```
@Path("/blah/{ver : v(1|2)}/ep")
```

Also, if the change is a single character only, use character set instead of the `|` operator:

```
@Path("/blah/{ver : v[12]}/ep")
```

Comment: The [JAX-RS specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311) doesn't say anything about spaces around the colon, so that will either break template parsing, or do nothing at all.

Comment: Yeah. This works. Why doesn't the anchors work? Could you shed some light on it?

Comment: Needing space around the colon is a resteasy thing (due to a bug in it)